# Hazelcast - Why entryprocessors are not using Portable?

Tags: java, distributed-computing, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I need to implement cross platform map using portable serialization

I need to insert / update too many values so I use Entryprocessor for insert or update as shown below:

```
package com.mycompany.common;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import com.hazelcast.core.Offloadable;
import com.hazelcast.map.AbstractEntryProcessor;
import com.hazelcast.nio.ObjectDataInput;
import com.hazelcast.nio.ObjectDataOutput;
import com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.Portable;
import com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableReader;
import com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableWriter;

public class MyEntryProcessor extends AbstractEntryProcessor<String, MapValue> implements Offloadable, Portable {

    private static final long   serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private MapValue mapValue;


    public MyEntryProcessor() {

    }

    public MyEntryProcessor(MapValue mapValue) {
        this.mapValue = mapValue;
    }

    @Override
    public Object process(Entry<String, MapValue> entry) {

        MapValue valueToSet = null;
        if (null == entry.getValue()) {
            valueToSet = mapValue;
        } else {
            MapValue valueToUpdate = entry.getValue();
            valueToUpdate.setData(mapValue.getData());
            valueToSet = valueToUpdate;
        }

        entry.setValue(valueToSet);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getExecutorName() {
        //return NO_OFFLOADING;
        return OFFLOADABLE_EXECUTOR;
    }

    @Override
    public int getClassId() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getFactoryId() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void readPortable(PortableReader reader) throws IOException {
        if (reader.readBoolean("_has__mapValue")) {
            ObjectDataInput in = reader.getRawDataInput();
            mapValue = in.readObject();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void writePortable(PortableWriter writer) throws IOException {
        boolean hasMapValue = (mapValue != null);
        writer.writeBoolean("_has__mapValue", hasMapValue);
        if (hasMapValue) {
            ObjectDataOutput out = writer.getRawDataOutput();
            out.writeObject(mapValue);
        }

    }


}
```

MyEntryProcessor implements Portable .. When there is one hazelcast member there is no problem. When I send elements for processing using hzlMap.executeOnKeys() no error occurs.

But when there are more members I get the below exception from members..

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.operations.Backup'
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:75)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:155)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:128)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OutboundOperationHandler.send(OutboundOperationHandler.java:51)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.sendSingleBackup(OperationBackupHandler.java:217)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.makeBackups(OperationBackupHandler.java:189)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.sendBackups0(OperationBackupHandler.java:108)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.sendBackups(OperationBackupHandler.java:74)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.handleResponse(OperationRunnerImpl.java:272)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:195)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:120)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:100)
    at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:127)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture$1.run(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:243)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractPartitionMessageTask.execute(AbstractPartitionMessageTask.java:78)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.unblock(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:239)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.unblockAll(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:225)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.unblockAll(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:229)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.complete(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:363)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.complete(Invocation.java:632)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.notifyNormalResponse(Invocation.java:314)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.notifyError(Invocation.java:273)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.sendResponse(Invocation.java:196)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperation$3.handleResponse(EntryOperation.java:337)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperation$3.sendResponse(EntryOperation.java:310)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.sendResponse(Operation.java:353)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.sendResponseAfterOperationError(OperationRunnerImpl.java:367)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.handleOperationError(OperationRunnerImpl.java:361)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:198)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:120)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:100)
    at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:96)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:33)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:155)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.invokeOnPartition(ClientProxy.java:204)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:198)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.executeOnKeyInternal(ClientMapProxy.java:1294)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.executeOnKey(ClientMapProxy.java:1287)
    at com.mycompany.client.service.MapRepo.putEntriesUsingEntryProcessor(MapRepo.java:31)
    at com.mycompany.client.ClientAppMain.main(ClientAppMain.java:25)
Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryBackupOperation'
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:75)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.writeObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:252)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeObject(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:370)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.operations.Backup.writeInternal(Backup.java:233)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.writeData(Operation.java:565)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:201)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:50)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:43)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:152)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:128)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OutboundOperationHandler.send(OutboundOperationHandler.java:51)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.sendSingleBackup(OperationBackupHandler.java:217)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.makeBackups(OperationBackupHandler.java:189)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.sendBackups0(OperationBackupHandler.java:108)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationBackupHandler.sendBackups(OperationBackupHandler.java:74)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.handleResponse(OperationRunnerImpl.java:272)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:195)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:120)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:100)
Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'com.hazelcast.map.AbstractEntryProcessor$EntryBackupProcessorImpl'
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:75)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.writeObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:252)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeObject(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:370)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryBackupOperation.writeInternal(EntryBackupOperation.java:72)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.writeData(Operation.java:565)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:201)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:50)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:43)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.writeObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:250)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mycompany.common.MapValue
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.write(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:242)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:43)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.writeObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:250)
    ... 24 more
```

Hazelcast is trying to serialize MyEntryProcessor using default serialization although it implements Portable?

Why is this happening? Am I missing sth?

How can it be corrected?

You can find sample project demonstrating the problem at :

https://github.com/simpleusr/hazelcastproblem

Please note that in order to reproduce the problem start two hazelcast members using hazelcast-dev1.xml and hazelcast-dev2.xml. When there is only one member there is no problem...

Comment: Can we see the full class definition ? What it extends and implements please. Also you don’t need to return a value if the caller doesn’t need it

Comment: @simpleusr, Since the exception is thrown from `InvokeOnPartitions.retryFailedPartitions` method, it means that your EP throws exception and EP sent to the backup partition. I try some scenarios but failed to get your exception. As Neil asked, can you share full EP definition and member configs as well?

Comment: @NeilStevenson I have added sample project demonstrating the problem...

Comment: @GokhanOner  I have added sample project demonstrating the problem... There is no exception from EP...

Comment: Hi everyone, please also note that this is a simplistic demo demonstrating my problem. MyProcessor actually operates on more complex object graph. But I am having the same serialization issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@simpleusr, I believe I found the cause. Please see below EP implementation.

The problem seems to be related to `EntryBackupProcessorImpl` used in `AbstractEntryProcessor`. It has a special precalculated `serialVersionUID` 
 as described in the source so setting EP as Portable causes this exception since it cannot convert `MapValue` object. When you implement both `EntryProcessor` and `EntryBackupProcessor` in your EP, the issue disappears.

```
public class MyEntryProcessor implements EntryProcessor<String, MapValue>, EntryBackupProcessor<String, MapValue>, Offloadable, Portable {

private static final long   serialVersionUID = 1L;


private MapValue mapValue;


public MyEntryProcessor() {

}

public MyEntryProcessor(MapValue mapValue) {
    this.mapValue = mapValue;
}

@Override
public Object process(Entry<String, MapValue> entry) {

    MapValue valueToSet = null;
    if (null == entry.getValue()) {
        valueToSet = mapValue;
    } else {
        MapValue valueToUpdate = entry.getValue();
        valueToUpdate.setData(mapValue.getData());
        valueToSet = valueToUpdate;
    }

    entry.setValue(valueToSet);

    return null;
}

@Override
public String getExecutorName() {
    //return NO_OFFLOADING;
    return OFFLOADABLE_EXECUTOR;
}

@Override
public int getClassId() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getFactoryId() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public void readPortable(PortableReader reader) throws IOException {
    if (reader.readBoolean("_has__mapValue")) {
        ObjectDataInput in = reader.getRawDataInput();
        mapValue = in.readObject();
    }
}

@Override
public void writePortable(PortableWriter writer) throws IOException {
    boolean hasMapValue = (mapValue != null);
    writer.writeBoolean("_has__mapValue", hasMapValue);
    if (hasMapValue) {
        ObjectDataOutput out = writer.getRawDataOutput();
        out.writeObject(mapValue);
    }

}

@Override
public EntryBackupProcessor<String, MapValue> getBackupProcessor() {
    return this;
}

@Override
public void processBackup(Entry<String, MapValue> entry) {
    process(entry);
}
}
```